# Speeding up an incredibly slow sshfs going through login ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, mount, remote, ssh-tunnel, sshfs

Sorry if this is answered somewhere and I have missed it.  I lack some understanding in how these things work in order to safely choose the best solution.

I, like many others, am working from home.

I work with large data files, and have access to reasonably powerful computing resources to process data.  For a long time I was using a vnc-viewer to work remotely but for various reasons it got really annoying to use and I started searching for an alternative.

I came across sshfs and it seems like the ideal choice. I work on mounted code/etc. remotely, with the creature comforts of my own PC/desktop set up, and then execute scripts remotely over ssh. I can then open remote plots etc of processed data locally.

I mount using  `sshfs remote-node:/home/me ~/work_sshfs/ -o follow_symlinks` which I have configured in my ~/.ssh/config file as:

```
Host login
        HostName login.server.com
        User usrname
        PasswordAuthentication true

Host remote-node
        HostName remote-node
        User usrname
        ProxyJump login
```

This works well, however when it comes to opening mounted processed files it can be really slow.  I have pretty good internet (Downs/Ups of 390/35Mbps) but when I am opening a file and watching nethogs I see max down-speeds of ~24Mbps. I also know from testing that the remote network's upload (~1 Gbps) is not the bottleneck.

From what I've read online I understand that the encryption overhead for sshfs (or just ssh) seems to be the bottleneck.

**Finally the question:** Does the fact I mount through a tunnel 'multiply' the effects of this? If yes, Is it possible to 'soften' the encryption on the  "login-portal <-- remote node" step of the mount?

These are on the "same" network which require login credentials to gain access to so I wouldn't be too nervous about relaxing this.  I would however want good encryption over the internet.

Sorry for the large amount of detail - I wanted to give context in case there is another solution, or something glaring I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: Traceroute to login server

```
traceroute to <login-server> (130.209.45.188), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.0.1)  1.926 ms  2.581 ms  3.472 ms
 2  * * *
 3  renf-core-2a-xe-910-0.network.*.net (62.***.70.**)  18.956 ms  19.265 ms  19.605 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  m674-mp2.*.lis.dial.*.net (62.*.*.162)  29.575 ms  29.989 ms  30.278 ms
 8  213.*.182.* (213.*.182.*)  38.575 ms  28.813 ms  33.320 ms
 9  *.telia.net (62.*.*.194)  33.623 ms *.telia.net (62.*.*.64)  28.854 ms *.telia.net (62.*.*.194)  35.838 ms
10  *.telia.net (213.*.*.98)  40.601 ms *.telia.net (62.*.*.211)  39.466 ms *.telia.net (62.*.*.239)  29.877 ms
11  * * *
12  jisc-ic-345131-ldn-b4.*.telia.net (*.*.*.131)  32.555 ms  27.628 ms  27.547 ms
13  ae24.*.ja.net (*.97.*.197)  31.632 ms  32.018 ms  27.961 ms
14  ae29.*.ja.net (*.97.*.2)  28.146 ms  32.859 ms  32.976 ms
15  ae31.*.ja.net (*.97.*.22)  33.075 ms  30.615 ms  40.368 ms
16  ae29.*.ja.net (*.*.33.42)  40.937 ms  37.516 ms  48.620 ms
17  ae31.*.ja.net (*.97.*.54)  39.851 ms  46.164 ms  47.362 ms
18  ae26.*.ja.net (*.97.*.26)  47.668 ms  47.919 ms  46.603 ms
19  *.97.*.2 (*.97.*.2)  56.201 ms  47.390 ms  46.254 ms
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: What is the latency (ping time) between you and the tunnel gateway, as well as between the tunnel gateway and the final server?

Comment: I was unable to test this, perhaps it is disabled on the servers?  
When I ping the login-server it hangs as though it does not hear back, and when I ping the remote-node from a shell on the login-server I get the message `ping: ssend socket: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Try traceroute, it'll give at least a rough hint (there won't be much of a difference between last and second-to-last hops).

Comment: Included this as an edit in my question.  I confess I do not have a clue whether or not any of the information could be even remotely 'weaponised' so I redacted some of the IP/addresses.  Call me paranoid/too lazy to research it haha

Comment: @user1686 was this a dead end?

Comment: I still strongly suspect it's related to that (latency causing sshfs to waste a lot of time just waiting for responses to arrive). What program are you opening the file with; can you compare it with e.g. `cp myfile /dev/null` or `dd if=myfile of=/dev/null bs=1M`? Does it become better or worse if you mount sshfs with `-o direct_io`? And can you compare it with e.g. downloading the same file via `lftp sftp://server`?

Comment: I am using CERN's [ROOT](https://ph-root-2.cern.ch/) analysis framework, opening the native *.root format datafiles.

'cp'-ing the file over the mount was peaked at 60Mbps but averaged 40-50Mbps, (compared to a steady-ish 40Mbps opening in ROOT).

'-o direct_io' pretty much halved the speed.

I'm not familiar with 'lftp' and looking online I'm not too sure how to use this with a login-tunnel.  If you can give any direction on this I'm happy to give it a go!